# Adding Checkbox to dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript programming. My program gives me another dropdown
menu based on the selection of the first dropdown menu. I am trying figure out how I can add checkbox into my dropdown so that I can check different types of fruits or
vegetables.

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // provs is an object but you can think of it as a lookup table
      
      var provs = {
            'Vegetable': ['Broccoli', 'Cabbage','Carrot'],
            'Fruit': ['Tomato', 'Apple','Orange']
          
          },
          // just grab references to the two drop-downs
          food_select = document.querySelector('#food'),
          type_select = document.querySelector('#type');
    
      // populate the drop-down
      setOptions(food_select, Object.keys(provs));
      // populate the town drop-down
      setOptions(type_select, provs[food_select.value]);
      
      // attach a change event listener to the drop-down
      food_select.addEventListener('change', function() {
        // get the towns in the selected province
        setOptions(type_select, provs[food_select.value]);
      });
        
      function setOptions(dropDown, options) {
        // clear out any existing values
        dropDown.innerHTML = '';
        // insert the new options into the drop-down
        options.forEach(function(value) {
          dropDown.innerHTML += '<option name="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
      }  
    };
    
    </script>
    <body>
    <select id="food"></select><br><br><br>
    <select id="type"></select>
    
    <body>
```

Comment: You can't add a checkbox unless you customize the select and overwrite it with divs. However, if you want the visitor to have the ability to select one or multiple items in the select just add the word multiple to the select tag

Comment: if you want a better styled option you can look at https://select2.org/ library (unaffiliated) there are others as well https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ slightly different and https://choices-js.github.io/Choices/ are vanilla js instead of jQuery